# To Imply a Dash and not Minus Sign in Math Mode

Tags: math-mode, punctuation

If I am in *Math mode*, and I want to name a variable, say *max-color*, here *max* and *color* are treated as two different variables and two spaces are placed around the minus sign. Now, what I really meant was a single variable called *max-color*.
How to achieve this inside *Math mode*.

Comment: `\text{max-color}`, assuming you are using `\usepackage{amsmath}`.

Comment: That appears to change the font, I am the variable name no longer looks like other math symbols.

Comment: In that case `max\text{-}color` will put just the dash into text mode. However, I would _not_ recommend that you do that.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to type out an algorithm where some variables are named this way. What would be the ideal way to achieve this?

Comment: My recommendation would be to define `\newcommand{\MaxColor}{\text{max-color}}` and then use `\MaxColor` instead. Then when you decide to change the formatting you just need to change the definition of it.  However, that is assuming you are using this for math. If you are using it for algorithm you should look at the appropriate packages.  See for instance [Print programs with its proper syntax](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25425/print-programs-with-its-proper-syntax/).

Comment: Am I missing something!!!? `max-color` in math mode means `m*a*x-c*o*l*o*r`.

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen: I agree. That was why I recommended _not_ to use `max\text{-}color`.

Comment: `\newcommand{\MaxColor}{\textnormal{max-color}}` would be more suitable, see the answer to this question : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98052/umlauts-in-math-mode .

Comment: Btw in unicode there are seperate characters for minus (−, U+2212) and hyphen (-, U+002D). But then there is also the En-Dash, which differs from the minus only by its vertical position (–, U+2013). Compare: `-–−+`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can take benefit of `\operatorname` which set things up so that in its argument hyphens give real hyphens and not minus signs:

```
\usepackage{amsmath} % only amsopn would suffice, actually
\newcommand{\var}[1]{{\operatorname{#1}}}
```

The additional pair of braces will keep the object from being considered an operator as far as spacing is concerned. If you want the variable name to appear in italics, change the definition into

```
\newcommand{\var}[1]{{\operatorname{\mathit{#1}}}}
```

In the following minimal example I use `\varA` for the first realization and `\varB` for the second one, take your pick.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\varA}[1]{{\operatorname{#1}}}
\newcommand{\varB}[1]{{\operatorname{\mathit{#1}}}}

\begin{document}
$\varA{max-color}=3$

$\varB{max-color}=2$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

In order to match the font of the other variables, it is probably best to use `\mathit`.  However, this will still set the dash as a minus.  To change that you can use `\text`, or for better consistency `\textnormal` around the dash, since `\text` adopts the font style of the text before the equation.  The command `\text` requires `amsmath`, whereas `\textnormal` is a standard LaTeX command but it is improved by the `amsmath` package, so that it scales appropriately in subscripts, superscripts and fractions.  Thus I recommend the following:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\( \mathit{max\textnormal{-}color} \)
\end{document}
```

You can conveniently package this as a command via

```
\newcommand{\maxcolor}{\mathit{max\textnormal{-}color}}
```

*EDIT* I originally thought an extra level of braces around the definition would be needed to make this directly usable in a sub-/superscripts, but T.Verron pointed out they are not necessary in this case.

Comment: Just curious... Why not simply `\textit` the whole thing?

Comment: You could use `\textnormal{\itshape ...}`, but (a) `\textit` on its own will change in a bold context, (b) there is no guarantee that the text `itshape` font is the same as the `mathit` font

Comment: Thank you a lot, that's indeed good reason. On a side note, I just tested it, the extra level of braces you mention in your last command definition seems superfluous. Latex seems to perform smarter command expansion than Tex. `:)`

Comment: @T.Verron You are right about the brackets!  It seems to be some special property of these font changing commands.

Comment: @AndrewSwann The expansion of `\mathit` starts, after some work, with `\bgroup`, followed by the font selection internal command; TeX accepts `_\bgroup...\egroup` as equivalent to `_{...}`

Comment: @egreg Many thanks for the explanation. I started digging through the code, but didn't get to the bottom.