# problem with math equations with package mathpazo

Tags: math-mode

I write a document in french language and i use the mathpazo package for mathematical equations. My problem is when I compile, the letters with accents does not appear and I do not want to use the command \ text {}. here is my code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\begin{document}
    $ élément $
\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I know,  `mathpazo`  does not use T1 encoding for maths. Anyway, you shouldn't write plain text in math mode – the letter spacing is bad (a word appears as a product of variables). Have you any serious reason to avoid the use of \text?

Comment: If you absolutely, positively must write `élément` in *math mode*, you should write it as `\acute{e}l\acute{e}ment`. See the posting [Trying to use “\~” to generate tilde symbol in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/281881/5001) for more information on entering "accents" in math mode and text mode.

Comment: I have a long document and I find replacing it with command \ text is hard work

Comment: Is it really harder to replace all math-mode instances of `élément` with `\text{élément}` than it is to replace them with `\acute{e}l\acute{e}ment`?

Comment: Text and math are different modes and you should use correct mark up. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/543180/umlaut-in-math-font-not-supported-automatically

Comment: @Mico : élément is just an example i have a lot of words in my math-mode. i will replace all, thank you all.